# Threejs isometric view and camera rotation

Tags: 3d, three.js, isometric

I have copied this code to make isometric view in my game:

```
var viewAngle = 22,
    near = 1,
    far = 1000,
    radians = -Math.PI / 4

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(viewAngle, w / h, near, far)
    camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ'
    camera.rotation.y = radians
    camera.rotation.x = Math.atan(-1 / Math.sqrt(2))
    camera.position.y = cameraY
    camera.scale.addScalar(1)
    scene.add(camera)
```

but I don't understand why I need all those camera rotations.

Can you explain what this code is doing and what for?

Thera are 3 angles here:

1. y angle
2. x angle
3. camera view angle

But why?

Comment: I didn't get something. Why do you use `PerspectiveCamera` instead of `OrthographicCamera` for isometric view?

Comment: Why should I use OrthographicCamera?